# How to deploy MERN stack with multi-tanent archtecture?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, e-commerce, multi-tenant

I had developed full stack e-commerce store in React and Node with MongoDB database. I want deploy it with multi-tenant architecture. Where every store owner will have their own domain name.

Let's say Admin Dashboard with different apis.
Add Product, Delete Product Orders etc,

Now how every store owner will have different frontend ( like theme )
and different domain pointing to their frontend.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. This is not mine, but it helped me a lot, take a look:
https://medium.com/geekculture/building-a-multi-tenant-app-with-nodejs-mongodb-ec9b5be6e737

For short it should have one frontend (React), one backend (Node) and several Mongo databases, one for each tenant (plus one for administration).